# On Windows 10, how can you click through a PowerPoint presentation while always being able to see the other slides?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint

**EDIT**

The basic problem I'm running into is this:  While doing a slideshow in fullscreen on a projector or large TV, while controlling the slideshow from my laptop, I need to be able to two things: 1) Keep the slide previews up on my laptop (not just the next and previous slides), and 2) Be able to select a slide preview from that list *to have the slideshow on the projector skip to it* - **without** the list of slide previews going away as soon as one is selected.

---

In Windows 7, this doesn't seem to be an issue, but when you run a PowerPoint slideshow on Windows 10, there doesn't seem to be a way to not only be able to see previews of other slides from your computer, but to also be able to keep seeing them without interruption as you click through the rest of the slideshow.

For example, notice how this image at http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EaI2Q9bGro0/T0WuLyYVszI/AAAAAAAAA-c/5Mx1yPHGRpw/s1600/loop-powerpoint-1.gif has a bar on the left with seven different slide previews on it:

[image]

In the past I've been able to begin a slideshow on Windows 7, and even though the slideshow would display on the projector or other screen, the list of slides would still be there on the laptop (though they would be moved to the bottom).  At that point if I needed to skip forward or back a few slides, I could just click on its preview, and the slideshow would skip to it on the projector without any trouble.

How do you do this during a slideshow on Window 10?  The closest option I can find is the See All Slides option, which takes you to a large grid; and that works great, except that as soon as you select another slide to go to, the See All Slides screen disappears.  How do you keep something like that up on your laptop while clicking through the slideshow?

Comment: ...you could just not use Presentation mode - just use Editing mode - same exact thing

Comment: @InterLinked Could you please elaborate?  I don't know a whole lot about PowerPoint.

Comment: Your picture of PowerPoint 2010 is literally editing mode, not presenting it all. When you open a PowerPoint, by default, that is the screen it goes to, 2010 or 2013

Comment: But I would want it show the slides in full screen on the other monitor / projector.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your PowerPoint File.
2. Go to View.
3. Then In the left press on"Normal" or what ever view you want.
   Also down in the right corner there is other options, check that too!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Windows issue at all; Presenter view changed from one version of PowerPoint to another. In PowerPoint 2010, for example, you get several slide thumbnails across the bottom of the laptop screen while in Presenter view. I don't recall offhand what happens in PPT 2013, but in 2016, you only get (IIRC) the next and previous slide thumbnails.

Other than using a different version of PPT to show the presentation, there's not much you can do.